# Why Does Mama Coco Look Old After Going to the Other World?

Tags: coco

I thought everyone in *Coco* becomes middle-aged when they enter the other world but in the last scene when Mama Coco dies she looks older than her parents..

[image: Mama Coco seen in the Land of the Dead as an older version than her parents]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Director Lee Unkrich answered this question in a [tweet](https://twitter.com/leeunkrich/status/936376529927290880). The age a person appears in the afterlife is the age they died.

> **@PogieJoe:** Hey @leeunkrich in the Land of the Dead do the characters appear as the age they died at, the age they are in their photos, or some third option?
>
> **@leeunkrich:** Age they passed away.
>
> [image: The tweet quoted above]

Comment: I disagree...cause the wife of hector died of old age(i saw that somewhere in the movie)...and i'm pretty sure all of Coco's relations looked middle-aged when they are in the other world...does this mean everyone died in middle-age??

Comment: There's really not much to disagree on if the director himself says it is so.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Fair enough

Comment: @THEEPICGUY That would make it a plot hole. Even if the writer or director is logically inconsistent. However it seems like a superficial plot hole.

Answer (score 11):

Disregarding whether it makes sense or not, everyone on the movie seems to have the same aspect they had on their offering photos (or A photo for those who don’t have an offering).

Out of universe the reason is obvious: so you can recognize them.
In universe is not established so we may connect those two facts however we wish.

Comment: Technically Mama Coco is shown in two pictures on the *ofrenda*, one as a few years old girl with her parents and the second when she's pretty old.

Comment: @Ister so it was not for us recognising them...nice point

Answer (score -1):

Lee Unkrich already said it, but characters are the age they died in the land of the dead.  You can see it as the bones on the characters give away their age.  Mama Imelda's face looks kind of saggy, like a woman in her 60's or early 70's.  Hector's face shows no lines or give, like the young man he was when he died.  Mama Coco lived well into her 80's or 90's, and she looks it.  Also, when Miguel and his family are crossing the bridge there's a child with her mother going the other way.  That, to me, was a giveaway about how old the dead characters are because there are children in the land of the dead.

Comment: I don't see how this adds any useful information to the existing answer